# How can i sort data from a txt?

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort this data chronologically, hopefully, by date and them by time, but right now I just want to sort it by date... the information is on a TXT file:

```
2022/5/10 at 10 the client Mari has appointment with the Dra. Windrunner
2022/1/5 at 2 the client Ian has appointment with the Dr. Stark
2022/1/4 at 10 the client Amy has appointment with the Dra. Windrunner
2022/1/5 at 2 the client Josh has appointment with the Dr. Stark
2022/2/22 at 5 the client Mike has appointment with the Dr. Pool
2022/2/22 at 4 the client Pedro has appointment with the Dr. Stark
```

This is my code right now:

```
Docs = ("Dr. Stark", "Dra. Windrunner", "Dr. Pool")
x = 0
loop = False

DocsConverter = {
    "0" : "Dr. Stark",
    "1" : "Dra. Windrunner",
    "2" : "Dr. Pool",
    "dr. stark": "Dr. Stark",
    "dra. windrunner" : "Dra. Windrunner",
    "dr. pool" : "Dr. Pool",
    "stark" : "Dr. Stark",
    "windrunner" : "Dra. Windrunner",
    "pool" : "Dr. Pool"
}

with open("appointment_hospital.txt", "a") as file_ap:
    pass


def menu():
    option = input("select a option 1. new appointment 2.show appointments 3. Exit: (1/2/3)\n")
    if option == "1":
        new_appointment()
    elif option == "2":
        print_appointments()
    elif option == "3":
        file_ap.close()
        exit()
    else:
        print("Wrong option")


def new_appointment():
    global x
    name_client = input("Enter the name of the client:\n")
    schedule_day = input("Enter the year, month and the day of the appointment:(Y/M/D)\n")
    schedule_time= input("Enter at what hour is the appointment:\n")
    while x != 3:
        print(f"{Docs[x]}, id = {x}")
        x += 1
    x = 0
    which_doc = input("Enter the name or the Id of the doctor: ")
    appointment_info = f"{schedule_day} at {schedule_time} the client {name_client} has appointment with the " \
                       f"{DocsConverter.get(which_doc)}\n"
    with open("appointment_hospital.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(appointment_info)

#this is where i tried to sort the information in the txt
def print_appointments():
    with open("appointment_hospital.txt", "r") as file:
        lines_appointments = []
        for line in file:
            temp = line.split()
            for i in temp:
                lines_appointments.append(i)
        lines_appointments.sort()
        with open("sort_appointments", "w") as sort_file:
            for i in lines_appointments:
                sort_file.writelines(i)
                sort_file.writelines(" ")
            sort_file.close()
    with open("sort_appointments", "w") as sort_file:
        read_appointments = sort_file.read()
        print(read_appointments)


while not loop:
    menu()
```

So in `def print_appointments():` I tried to sort the data, and this was my last tried, None of the ones I have done have given me a moderately positive result.

Comment: When you read the file line by line, you split the line by space and then add all the individual words into the array. When you sort you're going to see a list of all of the individual words sorted. Is that what you saw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some mistakes:

1. no file extension `open("sort_appointments"`
2. to sort by dates residual split the file by lines
3. when writing a list to a file, you need to open it for appending "a"
4. when reading a file, you must put the letter "r"

```
def print_appointments():
    with open("appointment_hospital.txt", "r") as file:
        lines_appointments = []
        for line in file:
            lines_appointments.append(line)
    lines_appointments.sort()

    with open("sort_appointments.txt", "a") as sort_file:
            sort_file.writelines(lines_appointments)


    with open("sort_appointments.txt", "r") as sort_file:
        read_appointments = sort_file.read()
        print(read_appointments)



print_appointments()
```